# How to fix overlapping timer in Days countdown

Tags: timer

I've created a countdown timer however when I attempted to add days into it, it shows 1 day & 24 hours... Anyone know how to fix this?

The timer runs on a divide node, connected to floor connected to value to string with a string input both connected to join strings, connected to a String length and a slice string, the string length is connected to subtract.

Boxed area is the days timer.

[image: Node SETUP]

Comment: Sorry, the node setup is too complex and to small to be legible - but to help you it might be necessary to inspect the nodetree in more detail. It would be nice if people trying to find a solution would not have to build this all themselves from that small screenshot, maybe you could upload your file here: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question?

Comment: as Gordon wrote - pls provide blend file. why? because a) we hardly can read your node tree b) you want help for free from us in our spare time, so you should make it as easy for us to help you c) the fact that you didn't get an answer within 13 hours for an easy GN questions (which are normally answered within 2-3 hours) might be a reason for that. thx for your understanding

Comment: Hi DTR... welcome to BSE. The comments have a fair point, here. In this case, without a share, the question is pretty much un-answerable, and vulnerable to closure as 'unclear'. Please edit, to avoid that.